# Does my simple javascript function, is the best way to add parameters to current URL

Tags: javascript, function

I wrote a javascript function that you can use to add parameters to your current URL. It returns your current URL with added parameters. I am not sure if this function will work on all browsers. Currently it works in my Chrome browser perfectly. Can you please tell me disadvantages of this function or how can I improve it or any other way to do the same thing?

```
function AddParamToURL(param_key, param_value)
{
    var currentURL, flag, newURL;

    currentURL = window.location.href;
    flag = currentURL.indexOf("?");

    if (flag == -1)
    {
        newURL = currentURL + "?" + param_key + "=" + param_value;
    }
    else
    {
        newURL = currentURL + param_key + "=" + param_value;
    }

    return newURL;
}
```

Comment: Are sure that it works properly? If there are any parameters already present in the url, you don't add a separator between the last parameter and the new one.

Comment: Thank you for the point, true I have to add "&" symbol in the second case.

Comment: Hope that one of these answers was what you wanted. If so, accepting one of them would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would send the path as a parameter to the function, because you won't always be just using the current window.href, you might want to send some other path as well.
You can then remove some redundancy by dealing with the param separator before adding to the path.
And this will work in a loop when you have more than one parameter to add.

```
function AddParamToURL(currentPath, param_key, param_value)
{
    var flag = currentPath.split("?");

    var paramSeparator = (flag.length <= 1) ? "?" : "&";

    return currentPath + paramSeparator + param_key + "=" + param_value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Should I take into account case when there might be no parameters after "?"? Like http://stackoverflow.com/?

Comment: It's up to you, as I commented above, the code is not longer :)

Comment: @sodawillow your's is a good point, it'll make the function more robust, I'll add it. The main point about putting the path in the calling parameters is that you might want to add three parameters to a url, not just one. This way it can work inside a loop. I've upvoted you for your idea.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the case where there could be a `?` without any key after it and added `&` in second case

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/0spsjeaL/3/

```
function AddParamToURL(param_key, param_value)
{
    var currentURL, flag, newURL;

    currentURL = window.location.href;
    flag = currentURL.split("?");

    if(flag.length <= 1)
    {
        newURL = currentURL + "?" + param_key + "=" + param_value;
    }
    else
    {
        newURL = currentURL + "&" + param_key + "=" + param_value;
    }

    return newURL;
}

alert(AddParamToURL('name', 'John'));
```

Comment: Why do you want to account for the case when there is no key after "?". When can such case happen?

Comment: Well this case is quite unlikely you are right, but the code is not longer and takes it into account :)

Answer (score 0):

You can inline a lot of stuff and `param_key + "=" + param_value` is duplicate code. Also you are forgetting `&` between parameters.

```
function AddParamToURL(param_key, param_value)
{
    var url = window.location.href;
    var newUrl = url.indexOf('?') < 0 ? url + '?' : url + '&';
    return newUrl + param_key + '=' param_value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Should I take into account case when there might be no parameters after "?"? Like stackoverflow.com?

Comment: @Timik I cannot imagine why the current URL would look like that. I don't think it's valid either. I tried in Firefox, I get redirected to `stackoverflow.com/?` (same with facebook)

Comment: You get redirected because stackoverflow's server deals with it, not necessarily because it isn't valid, because as far as I know, it's valid.